# Angular/rxjs promises - wait for one call to finish

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm struggling with making http calls wait for the previous one to finish before making the next. getThings calls my HTTP service which eventually sends a message that getMessage subscribes too. The reason I do this is because multiple components use this service and getThings(). I think I need to use promises but not sure how to implement.

### My component

```js
getThings(endpoint:any){
 this.getThingsService.getThings(endpoint);
 this.getThingsService.clearMessage();
 this.subscription = this.getThingsService.getMessage()
  .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
  .subscribe(message => {
    if(message) {
      this.data = message;        
    }
  })
}

//I want to wait for getThings to finish before calling getOtherThings.

getOtherThings(data:any){
 //make another http call
}
```

### service provider

```js
getThings(link:any){
interface ItemsResponse {
  results: string[];
}
this.http
  .get<ItemsResponse>(link, {
    observe: 'response'     
  })
  .retry(3)
  .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
  .subscribe(
    (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      switch (event.type) {
        case HttpEventType.Sent:
          break;
        case HttpEventType.Response:
          this.handleData(event.body);
      }
    },
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {        
       //error        
    }
  )
  }

 handleData(allAppDetails: any){
  this.clearMessage();   
  this.sendMessage(allAppDetails);
 }

 sendMessage(message: {}) {
  this.subject.next(message);
 }

 clearMessage() {
  this.subject.next(null);
 }

 getMessage(): Observable<any> {
  return this.subject.asObservable();
 }
```

### ////////New solution////////

### component:

```js
getThings(endpoint){
 this.subscription = this.getThingsService.getThings(endpoint)
  .flatMap(res => {
    if(res){
      console.log("get things complete, call getOtherThings")        
    }
    return this.getThingsService.getOtherThings(endpoint)
  })

  //this doesnt seem to catch anything
  .catch(err => {
    throw err
  })
  .subscribe(
    res => { // res is the result of the second http request
      if(res){
        console.log("other things response");
      }
  },
    //would this catch errors for both http calls?
    err => {
      console.log(err)
    });

 }
```

### Service

```js
getThings(link:any) {
 interface ItemsResponse {
  results: string[];
 }
 return this.http
  .get<ItemsResponse>(link, {
    observe: 'response'       
  })

getOtherThings(link:any) {
 interface ItemsResponse {
  results: string[];
 }
 return this.http
  .get<ItemsResponse>(link, {
    observe: 'response'       
  })
```

How would I capture http errors with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need promises to do this. You can accomplish this with the rxjs [flatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) operator.

```js
// component.ts
getThings(){
    this.getThingsService.getMessage()
        .flatMap(res => { // res is the result of the first http request
            // return observable of second http request;
            return this.getThingsService.getOtherMessage(); 
        })
        .subscribe(res => { // res is the result of the second http request
        });
}
```

So what is happening is `getMessage()` observable is being called first. When that finishes, `getOtherMessage()` observable is called.

Comment: I've updated my original post with my new solution based on your suggestions. How would I capture http errors with this new approach?

Comment: @Anthony you can use an rxjs (catch)[https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html] onto the observable sequence `.flatMap(...).catch(...)` or you can catch the error in your error callback of the subscribe, like you have in your code `.subscribe(res => {}, err => {});`

Comment: would .subscribe(res => {}, err => {});  catch errors for both http calls (updated my post)?

Comment: @Anthony yep, any errors within the observable sequence will be reported to the subscribe error callback